# How to use Django for rendering class based python file?

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am trying to learn Django. I have a python program which has class in it. All the examples that use python's class inherits Model.model. My class doesn't require any database. Can anyone help me how to set urls.py in django for this particular case?

What I have done so far is that I have imported the class, and the method inside the class from where I have to display my value. But it is always showing me some error.

This is what I have done in urls.py:

```
 1. from mysite.to_twitter_streaming import StdOutListener 
 2. url(r'^temp/$', StdOutListener().text_extract)
```

This StdOutListener is the class and text_extract is the function which has a value that I want to get printed.

I used this for printing:

```
 return render_to_response('TwitterApi.html', {'link': key, 'count':self.counter})
```

errors that I am getting are:

```
 1. TypeError at /temp/ 
 2. expected string or buffer
```

Comment: what error you are getting What you have tried in Django

Comment: Oh my post that in your question not in the comment

Answer (score 1):

ok in your urls.py

Change the format

```
 url(r'^temp/$', text_extract),
```

I am assuming you have `text_extract`  in your views

In your `views.py`

```
def text_extract(request):
    # do your stuff

    return render_to_response('TwitterApi.html', {'link': key, 'count':self.counter})
```

Comment: Actually this text_extract() method is defined under a class ('StdOutListener) and this method gets a value from another function defined in this class. 
So, I tried what you said, but it's not working.
NameError has occured.

Comment: @Hemant Django have some certain rule you must have to follow them.Please eleborate your question and put some code then only w e are able to help you

Comment: See.. If I use this python file and run it, there is no problem.
But when I want to use it in Django, I am not able to display the values that are present in text_extract() method. This method has a parameter, which takes value from the other method in the same class.
I read some where that View.py file only consider those functions which have no parameter. 
so how I am looking to solve this problem.